# Log columns that are truncated in SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis

I am bit new to SSIS. I am using SSIS 2012.The input files are excel, csv and txt.

The data has to be dumped from input files to the database. The size of the columns in the input files keep on changing, so i cant stick to a fixed length.  Changing the data type of connection managers in the package to `ntext` would solve this but we have performance constraint too. So customer prefers to truncate the extra data and intimate him  than affecting the performance.

Row redirection will give the rows that are truncated. But i want to intimate the customer in each file the columns that are truncated.

Is SSISDB tracks the data that are truncated. If so which table.

I am planning to write the truncated data to a separate files and then use script component to compare the length of each column. Is there a better way.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want to do that row redirection doesn't give you.   What does "intimate the customer" mean?

Comment: @TabAlleman To track the columns in each file that are truncated and send those columns using email task.

Answer (score 1):

Write the truncated rows (redirected) to a table.  You can add in a Derived Column to add in the name of the source file (if you get the package to hold it in a variable) between the redirecting Input and the Output that writes to a table.

If you truncate the table before each run, a simple ExecuteSQL to get the Count of rows into a variable, and then an email to the customer if Count>0, will work.

Comment: I want the columns that are truncated in each file. Not the file name itself

Comment: The Error Output automatically includes columns called ErrorCode and ErrorColumn.  You can work out the name of the column from the ErrorColumn value by looking up the column IDs in Advanced Editor.

Comment: I've never seen an error message in SSIS that said which column was truncated.   It always just says "data would be truncated".

Comment: You can set the input to "Redirect row" to the error output on truncation.  This is not perfect, though, as if multiple columns are/would be truncated in one row, only the ID of the first column is recorded in the ErrorColumn column.

Comment: Since SSIS 2012 the Lineage IDs behind each column are generated at run time. It is not possible to find the column names in your error flow.

Comment: @JodyT.  Ouch!  That's not exactly an improvement.  I've been looking for a way to programmatically add in the column name from the ID anyway, because even with the SSIS 2008 persistent column IDs, it's a pain to read the .DTSX file and make a lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as far as I know, there is nothing in SSIS which automatically tracks which columns are truncated.

There are a couple ways I can think of to handle this and they both require the main logic occurring in a script transformation.

If I had to do this, I would create a script component that "predicts" which columns will be truncated before passing them on to the rest of the dataflow.

As you use LEFT() to truncate each string to the required length, you can check afterwards to see if the old string and the new string are the same.

If not, then you know truncation has occurred and you can populate a variable to use in a send email task.

Or you can truncate the columns with derived columns first and then use a script transformation to compare the old column with the new column.   Same logic.

Comment: Yes - SSIS's error handling on input is all very well, but limited.  If the data is very unreliable, I find it much easier to be agnostic about data types (set all columns to long DT_STR/ST_WSTR) on input, and do the data cleansing in explicit operations (either SSIS, scripted C# or even SQL) inside the package.

Comment: @SebTHU I don't follow you.  Does it seem that I am suggesting using SSIS Error Handers?   That wasn't my intent, and I'm not sure what I wrote that could be interpreted that way.

Comment: not at all.  I'm agreeing with your suggestion that it's better to do this kind of thing within the package flow.